# What happens when a buffer is to small to hold some data

Tags: c

My question is why the following code snippet doesn't crash ?

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const char* source = "SomeText";
    char* dest = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)); // isn't this wrong ?

    strcpy(dest, source);

    printf("%s\n", dest);

    free(dest);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is indeed wrong, and invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcpy` will overrun the buffer when it is too small to hold the string being copied. This will cause undefined behaviour or even program crash (segfault) because `strcpy` will try to write into memory which is not allocated to the buffer. You can't rely on what happens. Next time you run your program, it may very well crash. Here are some fixes I suggest.

```
// in main

const char *source = "SomeText";
char *dest = malloc(strlen(source) + 1); // +1 for the null byte at the end
if(dest != NULL) { // check for NULL
    strcpy(dest, source);
    printf("%s\n", dest);
    free(dest);
}
else {
    printf("not enough memory\n");
}
```

`strlen` doesn't count the null byte in a string, so you have to allocate one extra byte for it to be copied by `strcpy` from the `source` string. You should check the result of `malloc` for null. Also, you should not cast the result of `malloc`. There's no benefit and it can lead to bugs if you forget to include the `stdlib.h` header file.

Comment: Your point about casting result of malloc is not quite correct. Most compilers (like MSVC++) will (and should) generate an error in such case. Assigning void* to pointer of certain type always must be done using explicit casting via reinterpret_cast<> or c-style cast.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek I am talking in the context of `C`. You're right. In `C++`, you do need to cast the result of `malloc` else compiler will throw an error.

Comment: Now I see that small, barely visible tag now, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

Because it is **undefined behavior** and can happen to work or not. Writing to unallocated space is a risky operation which is not guaranteed to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Behavior in such a case is undefined. In fact a memory outside the reserved place is overwritten. This memory can hold some important information or not. It may be mapped into address space of the process or not. If it is not mapped a system error happens. If it is mapped, then the most probably this memory contains values required for correct working of malloc and free, so you may expect crash on the next malloc or free. If you overwrite a larger part of memory you may write into some other dynamically allocated buffer.

In your case you are overwriting only 8 bytes outside the reserved place. The most probable is that those 8 bytes are mapped into address space and are not used at all. This is why nothing happened. The exact behavior depends on the particular implementation of malloc and free..

Answer (score 1):

Luck?

But usually malloc grabs memory that is convenient for the OS. So maybe it is 1K